# Precise definition of locally closed complex curve

Tags: reference-request, definitions, several-complex-variables

In [Stein Manifold and Holomorphic Mappings, by Forstnerič](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783642222498), I refer to Definition 8.9.9:
An exposed point is a point belonging to a certain subset $\Sigma$ of $\Bbb C^2$, enjoying certain properties.
This set $\Sigma$ is pointed as

> Locally closed complex curve, possibly with boundary.

A complex curve is the holomorphic image of some open set $D\subseteq\Bbb C$ (including the whole $\Bbb C$).

Closed means that it coincides with its closure.

Calling $F\colon D\to\Bbb C^2$ holomorphic, we can extend it smoothly to the boundary $\overline D$ (in case $D\neq\Bbb C$) and define $\Sigma:=F(\overline D)$.

What does "locally" mean?

Why "possibly with boundary"? Does it have to have boundary or not?

Can somebody explain? Thanks

Comment: You can't always extend to the boundary smoothly. Locally means locally in $\mathbb{C}^2$, not locally in $D$. Possibly with boundary means parameterized locally by a closed half plane.